# How To Store And Show Selected Value Result To Respective Radio Button For All Radio Button In Blazor Sever

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, radio-button, blazor

Here I have simple Multiple choice question and answer blazor server app, where user select one of the answer out of 4 answer options for the question and if the answer is correct `<span class="badge badge-success">Correct Answer</span>` correct message is displayed and if wrong `<span class="badge badge-danger">Wrong Answer</span>`wrong message is displayed to the respective question.
Now the problem is that when ever I select answer option of new question the correct answer or wrong answer message of previous questions is not displayed to that respective questions.

Any help will be grate. Thank you

Bleow is Mcq.Razor

```
<style>
  .hide {
         display: none !important;
        }

  .show {
         display: initial !important;
        }
</style>
@{
    int quizIndex = 0;
 }
@foreach (var item in questions)
{
<p>@item.QuestionDetail</p>

@if (item.QuestionAndAnswerId == questionId)
{
    <p class="@HideShowCss">
        @if (isCorrect == 1)
        {
            <span class="badge badge-success">Correct Answer</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span class="badge badge-danger">Wrong Answer</span>
        }
</p>
}
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="@item.Option1, @item.QuestionAndAnswerId" @onchange="GetRadioButtonValue" name="@quizIndex">@item.Option1
     </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="@item.Option2, @item.QuestionAndAnswerId" @onchange="GetRadioButtonValue" name="@quizIndex">@item.Option2
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="@item.Option3,@item.QuestionAndAnswerId" 
        @onchange="GetRadioButtonValue" name="@quizIndex">@item.Option3
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="@item.Option4,@item.QuestionAndAnswerId" @onchange="GetRadioButtonValue" name="@quizIndex">@item.Option4
     </label>
</div>

    quizIndex++;
}
```

Below is my code

```
public List<QuestionAndAnswer> questions = new List<QuestionAndAnswer>();
public string HideShowCss;
public int isCorrect;
public int questionId;
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var list = db.QuestionAndAnswer.ToList();
    HideShowCss = "hide";
    questions = list;
}
public void GetRadioButtonValue(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    
    var getValue = args.Value.ToString();
    var splitValue = getValue.Split(",");
    var getSelectedValue = splitValue[0];
    var getQuestionId = splitValue[1];
    int.TryParse(getQuestionId, out int QuestionId);
    var getAnswer = db.QuestionAndAnswer.Where(x => x.QuestionAndAnswerId == QuestionId).FirstOrDefault().Answer;
    if (getSelectedValue == getAnswer)
    {
        questionId = QuestionId;
        HideShowCss = "show";
        isCorrect = 1;

    }
    else
    {
        questionId = QuestionId;
        HideShowCss = "show";
        isCorrect = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this exact same questions a few days ago, and get some answers?  If so, you should explain what changes you've made since you last asked it.

Comment: @sudip chand, Thousands and one apologies...I've forgotten about your question. Rest assured that this night you'll go to bed knowing that your answer   has been supplied.

Comment: Yes I have asked but none of the answer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your answer...Copy and test it, inspect the code and tell me what else you need.

```
@page "/"

@foreach (var question in questions)
{
    <p>
         <span>@question.Title</span>
    

        @foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
        {
        <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">

        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="@answer.Text" @onchange="OnChange" 
        name="@question.ID" id="@answer.Text" 
        checked="@(question.SelectedAnswer?.Equals(answer.Text,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))" />@answer.Text" 
        
        </label>
        

        </div>
        }
      
            @if (question.IsCorrectAnswer == null  )
            {
                <span class="badge badge-success"></span>
            }
            else if((bool) question.IsCorrectAnswer)
            {
                <span class="badge badge-success">Correct Answer</span>
            }
            else
            {
               <span class="badge badge-danger">Wrong Answer</span>
            }
            
    </p>
    
}


@code {


    private void OnChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
      
       var selectedAnswer = args.Value.ToString();

        var data = (from question in questions
                     from answer in question.Answers
                     where answer.Text == selectedAnswer
                          select new { answer.QuestionID, answer.IsCorrect }).First();

        var _question = (from question in questions
                         where question.ID == data.QuestionID
                         select question).First();

        _question.SelectedAnswer = selectedAnswer;


        _question.IsCorrectAnswer = data.IsCorrect;
             
    }

  
    private List<Question> questions = new List<Question> { new Question{ID = 1, SelectedAnswer="", Title = "fervid means: ", 
                                    Answers = new List<Answer>
                                              { new Answer {ID = 1, Text = "thin", IsCorrect = false, QuestionID = 1},
                                                new Answer {ID = 2, Text = "hot", IsCorrect = true, QuestionID = 1},
                                                new Answer {ID = 3, Text = "bare", IsCorrect = false, QuestionID = 1},
                                                new Answer {ID = 4, Text = "fast", IsCorrect = false, QuestionID = 1}} 
                                    },
                                new Question{ID = 2, Title = "pallid means: ", 
                                    Answers = new List<Answer>
                                              { new Answer {ID = 1, Text = "average", IsCorrect = false, QuestionID = 2},
                                                new Answer {ID = 2, Text = "quality", IsCorrect = false, QuestionID = 2},
                                                new Answer {ID = 3, Text = "fleeting", IsCorrect = false, QuestionID = 2},
                                                new Answer {ID = 4, Text = "colorless", IsCorrect = true, QuestionID = 2}} 
                                    }};

    public class Question
    {
        public int ID {get;set;}
        public string Title {get;set;}
        public bool? IsCorrectAnswer = null;
        public string SelectedAnswer { get; set; } 
        public List<Answer> Answers  {get;set;} = new List<Answer>{};
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public int ID {get;set;}
        public string Text {get;set;}
        public bool IsCorrect {get;set;}
        public int QuestionID {get;set;}

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much enet this solves my problem,  one thing `from question in questions` in data,  what does it used for did you use it for join or something else, and one more thing can you provide me code for bootstrap pagination in this, I have implemented BlazorPagination from github but I cannot edit its html.

Comment: @sudip chand, yes, I'm using LINQ Queries to get the QuestionID of the selected answer in order to get the answer itself. We get the selected value via ChangeEventArgs, thus enabling us to find out which answer was selected. We then retrieve the question the answer belongs to, and use it for further manipulation such as displaying the messages to indicate that an answer is correct or wrong, etc. This is not rocket science, but definitely something  that requires one to be knowledgeable,  experienced and intelligent. See this Dictionary web site ( https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/clove )

Comment: It has a multiple choice questions quiz component, which is done badly, and very often  does not reflect the word searched. I would never code like that, and  my code is robust without bugs. Do you remember that I've told you that you should plan and design this system beforehand ? Otherwise, you'll need to repeatedly change your code:... Implementing pagination may require some planning and work, and merits a question or two, which you'll have to post in stackoverflow.

Comment: Unfortunately,  today I've made up my mind  not to post  in stackoverflow as from now. But if you're curious I can tell you that privately. You may find my email in my profile page. Hope others would help you.

Comment: you provide very good answers which always works for me, I don’t know the reason of yours not posting answer onward, but that will be a huge loss to the community. So I request you to keep providing your valuable answers.

Comment: Please keep posting your answers you are saver